# Axios: Users attempts before Login

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

when i send "EnvioLogin" with the correct email / password i get the access token from "/login" but i cant get "/users" after that only  before
When i inspect in my browser i get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBJK0.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWQEG.jpg

How can i run created hooks after the user attempts to login?

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "login",


  data() {
    return {
      showError: false,
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
     async created() {
    const response = await axios.get("api/users", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    });

    console.log(response);
  },

  methods: {
    async EnvioLogin() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        const status = JSON.parse(response.status);
        if (status == "200") {
          console.log(response);
          this.$router.push("intermediorotas");
          this.showLogin = false;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.showError = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.showError = false;
        }, 2000);
      }
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the created hook could be in separate method named `getUsers` then call it in `EnvioLogin` method :

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "login",


  data() {
    return {
      showError: false,
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
   this.getUsers();
  },

  methods: {
   async getUsers(){
   const response = await axios.get("api/users", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    });

    console.log(response);
  },
    async EnvioLogin() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        const status = JSON.parse(response.status);
        if (status == "200") {
         this.getUsers();
          console.log(response);
          this.$router.push("intermediorotas");
          this.showLogin = false;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.showError = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.showError = false;
        }, 2000);
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: But im still getting {status: "Token is Invalid"} from users. Do you know what can it be?

Comment: I think this is related to backend implementation